# Something wrong in creating mysql trigger

Tags: mysql

Hi i'm trying to create below trigger

CREATE TRIGGER TRIGBEFORE INSERT ON employee
FOR EACH
ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE employee SET userId = userId +1 WHERE userId >1;
END

it is giving me below mysql error, please suggest what is wrong in it.

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

Comment: What does your trigger do? You cannot modify `employee` table, because the trigger is created on this table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot to set the delimiter and misspelled a word:

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER TRIG BEFORE INSERT ON employee 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
    UPDATE employee SET userId = userId +1 WHERE userId >1; 
END;
|
delimiter ;
```

If you don't set another delimiter than `;` the statement will end at the first `;` and your trigger definition will be incomplete. You  need to tell MySQL that the stamentment should end at the delimiter you defined. After that you can set the delimiter back with `delimiter ;`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo mistake `TRIGBEFORE`: [manual here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html)

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name BEFORE INSERT ON ...
```